# Chrome disappears/hangs after reboot?

Tags: chrome-for-android, cache

I'm using Android 4.1.2 that's rooted.

Because Google Chrome has a big size, especially the cache (which is troublesome to delete it every visiting a new site), i moved my Chrome to SD Card by using Titanium Backup.(In my phone chrome is a system app so i deleted it and reinstall the Playstore version)

But now, when i reboot my phone, my Chrome will either crashes or disappears entirely at startup. Is there any way to solve this?

If that's impossible, is there any way to move cache to SD Card? Because that what makes my internal memory loses much space.

My phone is Oppo Find Way (U7015) - it's only released in china and southeast asia :)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange! The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you put each question in a separate question post. Please edit your post down to one question, and create new posts to ask any further questions. You'll get better answers that way.

Comment: Or just remove the second part: A reboot is needed when a reboot is needed, not when the day changes. I reboot my devices only when something "got stuck", which doesn't happen more than once or twice a month usually. On some devices, even much less frequent.

Comment: @Izzy I was going to leave this for a separate question, but there is a reason why a manufacturer might recommend this: they (think they) have introduced a memory leak in a core system component such as a driver. In that case, a reboot every so often may be the only way to stop the device running out of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i already deleted the second part :) Thanks for letting me know :D

Comment: @DanHulme Agreed, and that's probably overlapping with my "getting stuck". "every so often" = "when it's needed" ≠ "every 24h". I doubt there's a definite time table ;) // user46097: You might wish to take a look at our [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info), which also lists available alternatives concerning your app-move.

Comment: So if the manufacturer/device aren't stating that the device needed to be rebooted at a definite time table, it's okay to let my device run for days or months without rebooting right?

@Izzy: Okay then, i'm going to ask if it is possible to move cache to SD Card, but i guess i'll leave it as a different question lol

Comment: Let's say if everything runs fine, you definitly do not need to reboot. When in doubt, it doesn't hurt. And yes, make that a separate question – **after** having read the [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info). If you still need to ask then, that is :)